# Firebase retrieve value after incremented

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am incrementing a value by using

```
const increment = firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

this.fb.afs.collection(colId).doc(docId).set({
  invoiceCount: increment
}, {
  merge: true
})
```

How can I retrieve the incremented value right after to proceed using this value?

Is the following sufficient or critical in same-time access situations:

```
this.fb.afs.collection(colId).doc(docId).set({
  count: increment
}, {
  merge: true
})
.finally(() => {
  this.fb.afs.collection(colId).doc(docId).valueChanges().pipe(first()).subscribe(res => {
    //proceed with res.count
  })
})
```

What would be a better way?

Comment: firebase is a realtime, so if you are listening to valueChanges it will fire when you do the update. What are your intentions here?

Comment: Exactly, since using `pipe(first())` I am only retrieving the current value which is supposed to be the one I just added using my `increment`.
Would using `get()` instead be a better approach?
Is it safe to use if there are many increments going on at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) on the firestore document after update, which gets the document you have just updated:

```ts
const docRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.fb.afs.collection(colId).doc(docId).set({
  count: increment
}, {
  merge: true
})

docRef.get().pipe(
  map(doc => doc.data())
)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Nope, that does not work as `then()` after `set()` returns a Promise<void> which makes it impossible to get the reference inside the `then`

Comment: You are completely correct, sorry about that. Try updated answer.